# Split transcript into transcripts for different speakers

Tags: python, string, transcription

I have a transcript with different speakers, for instance (new.txt):

```
spk_0: Default transcript, containing many sentences. Such as this. 
spk_1: Blablabla
spk_2: Blablablaba fjdslf
```

I want to create different strings from this transcript that only contains the text said by a speaker, so for instance:

```
new_spk_0 = "Default transcript, containing many sentences. Such as this."
new_spk_1 = "Blablabla"
```

How could I go about doing this?

Comment: This is a problem statement. What have you tried? Please demonstrate with code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it using the method provided in: [Reading only the words of a specific speaker and adding those words to a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34040242/reading-only-the-words-of-a-specific-speaker-and-adding-those-words-to-a-lis)

Here a regex match at the beginning of the sentence is used to indicate the prevalence of different speakers and is later split into multiple key-value pairs in a dictionary.